# SignalR with long process: send intermediate messages

Tags: javascript, azure, signalr, azure-functions

I am using SignalR to start long computations on server side and post a message to the client when the result is available.
The input bindings is an HTTP request.

I would like to be able to send multiple messages back in order to notify the client of the differents steps of the process (eg, computation starts, computation ends, etc..).

I tried pushing different messages to context.bindings.signalRMessages but I see that everything is sent together at the end of the whole process. Is there a way to send several messages at different times?

Another related issue is that my HTTP request on client side remains stuck until the end of the process. I would like to be able to post a quick response early, since I get the response via a signalR message.

Here is my server code :

```
module.exports = async function(context, req) {
    let ID = context.bindingData.invocationId;

    context.bindings.signalRMessages = [];
    const messageQueue = context.bindings.signalRMessages;

    var postMessage = (message) => {
        message.userId = req.query.userId;
        message.isPrivate = true;
        messageQueue.push(message);
    };

    let preProcessData = preProcess(req.body.input);

    let startMessage = {
        "target": "optimStart",
        "arguments": [{ preProcessData: preProcessData }]
    };
    postMessage(startMessage); // <<<< I want this one to be sent immediately

    try {
        let optimOutput = await computeOptim(req.body.input, ID); // that's the long process

        let response = {
            optimId: ID,
            optimOutput: optimOutput
        };

        let optimCompleteMessage = {
            "target": "optimComplete",
            "arguments": [response]
        };
        postMessage(optimCompleteMessage);
    } catch (err) {
        // ....
    }

};
```

Am I doing anything wrong or is it just not possible ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with a simple HTTP triggered function since bindings resolve only once the execution of the function completes.

For your scenario, [durable functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp) would be the perfect choice.

You would still have a HTTP Triggered function ([client function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-types-features-overview#client-functions)) to start on orchestration and return immediately. In the [orchestration function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-types-features-overview#orchestrator-functions), you would have separate [activity functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-types-features-overview#activity-functions) for the processing and for sending updates to the client using the SignalR binding.

Comment: thank you for the clarification! I tried both signalR and durable functions but didn't think of mixing them together. I'll give it a shot.